# Enable to add more than 100 values on multi select picklist field in salesforce

Tags: multi-select

I have a custom multiselect picklist field with 500 values in the application and now i need to enable the selection of more than 100 values at a time on any record.

As per the salesforce limitation, we cannot select more than 100 values at a time in multiselect picklist field.

Can you please suggest me any ideas over this? How to implement this?

Any alternatives possible on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted already, SalesForce imposes a limit on multi-picklist selection fields of 500 values.  The overall limit (of 500 values) can technically be increased, but the selection limit of 100 values cannot (per [this SF Help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334115&type=1)).

I would also take into consideration the limitations multi-selection picklist fields can impose on your organization.  Please [reference this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide/vpm_designer_about_multi-select_choices.htm) to see what I mean here.  Although they may seem like a great idea in the short term, they can be a bit of a nightmare when it comes to flows/automation/reports you might want to set up in the future.

Your question does not mention if the application is internal or external and what the intent behind the field is, so it's difficult to provide a more specific answer. Some solutions I can think of are as follows:

1. If you're set on the use of multi-selection picklist fields, can you break up your current choices into categories and have a field for each? Even from a user perspective, trying to review 500 fields at once with the potential to select over 100 options could be pretty overwhelming, and breaking it up could help here.
2. If this is internal, and all choice options belong to the same field, you could consider creating a custom object for that field, which would have a record for each choice selection under it.  Then, you could create a 'junction' object to create a related list to the main object that currently houses your multi-select picklist field. (Think Quote -> Pricebook -> Pricebook Line Items relation).  You could then relate your grandchild objects (line items from the example above) to your parent object (quote) through the child (pricebook). [idea from [this answer]](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A92R8SAJ)

If this answer was helpful, please select it as the best answer so it can be helpful to others. Happy SalesForcing!